# Javascript - How to get data from a json file?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get data from a JSON file from a different javascript file. I want to console log the title from config.json via main.js.

I am trying to learn about JSON and javascript and how they interact with this project. I have already tried using import and export, it tells me that is an unexpected identifier. I have tried researching it lots.

JSON Code:

```
{
    "Info": {
    "title": "Pretty Cool Title",
    "bio": "Pretty cool bio too in my opinion."
    }
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
import Info from "config.json";

var info = Info

var title = info.title

console.log(title);
```

My expected outcome is that the title (which I set to "pretty cool title") will be logged in the console. My actual result however is "unexpected identifier"

Comment: Try `var info = Info.Info`. If I understand imports correctly, `Info` is the whole `json` object; you have to access the `Info` value of that json.

Comment: there is no import in javascript... are you using typescript?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with React or `import`.

Answer (score 1):

By using `fetch`.

```
// return json data from any file path (asynchronous)
function getJSON(path) {
    return fetch(path).then(response => response.json());
}

// load json data; then proceed
getJSON('config.json').then(info => {
    // get title property and log it to the console
    var title = info.title;
    console.log(title);  
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is how to do it using *async* and *await*.

```
async function getJSON(path, callback) {
    return callback(await fetch(path).then(r => r.json()));
}

getJSON('config.json', info => console.log(info.title));
```

Comment: `getJSON()` has no return and `fetch()` is asynchronous

Comment: @charliefl fixed that.